# Read data on your thing-speak channel using on/off button in jquery?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I have the following code, it does the switch on and off. But I want now to be able read data on my `thingspeak` channel, when the value is 1 and value is 0 using the read channel url. I am struggling to this write, please help me and thanks.

```
<div class = "wrapper" align = "center">
  <div class="btn-group" id="toggle_event_editing">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info locked_active">OFF</button>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default unlocked_inactive">ON</button>
</div> 
<div class="alert alert-info" id="switch_status">Switched off.</div>
 </div>

  $('#toggle_event_editing button').click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('locked_active') || $(this).hasClass('unlocked_inactive')){
        /* code to do when unlocking */
        $('#switch_status').html('Switched on.');
$.ajax({
    url:'https://api.thingspeak.com/update?api_key=DLQ0F7W5FGVO1I9Q&field8=1',
    type:'GET',
    data:{
    format:'text'
      },
    success:function(response){
    alert(response);
      },
    error:function(){
    $('#error').text("There was an error while processing your request.Please try again");
    $('#singlebtn').append(data);
      }

      });

      }

    }else{
        /* code to do when locking */
        $('#switch_status').html('Switched off.');
$.ajax({
    url:'https://api.thingspeak.com/update?api_key=DLQ0F7W5FGVO1I9Q&field8=0',
    type:'GET',
    data:{
    format:'text'
      },
    success:function(response){
    alert(response);
      },
    error:function(){
    $('#error').text("There was an error while processing your request.Please try again");
    $('#singlebtn').append(data);
      }

      });

      }
    }

    /* reverse locking status */
    $('#toggle_event_editing button').eq(0).toggleClass('locked_inactive locked_active btn-default btn-info');
    $('#toggle_event_editing button').eq(1).toggleClass('unlocked_inactive unlocked_active btn-info btn-default');
});
```

Comment: are you getting back response from ajax on success ? because i cant understand what issue you have

Comment: My issue i want my button to do an ajax call to my channel, im not getting any success that is my issue. Meaning if my button is switch between on, must do an update to my channel and vice versa.

Comment: when i run your ajax im getting response: 7231 and this part of your code if($(this).hasClass('locked_active') || $(this).hasClass('unlocked_inactive')){  will always send &field8=1 if is ON or OFF

Comment: @Ivan can you share your logic, will run it on my side as a test and see if i am getting this same behavior.

Comment: here at stackoverflow press F12 -> console , paste the ajax only and hit enter and you will get response as alert $.ajax({
    url:'https://api.thingspeak.com/update?api_key=DLQ0F7W5FGVO1I9Q&field8=1',
    type:'GET',
    data:{
    format:'text'
      },
    success:function(response){
    alert(response);
      },
    error:function(){
    $('#error').text("There was an error while processing your request.Please try again");
    $('#singlebtn').append(data);
      }

      });

Comment: @Ivan that request to me does the update on my thingspeak channel as positive value, i want to do that within the button itself when switch.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work for you about ajax

```js
$('#toggle_event_editing button').click(function(){
  if($(this).hasClass('locked_active')){
    /* code to do when unlocking */
    $('#switch_status').html('Switched on.');
    $.ajax({
      url:'https://api.thingspeak.com/update?api_key=DLQ0F7W5FGVO1I9Q&field8=1',
      type:'GET',
      data:{
        format:'text'
      },
      success:function(response){
        alert(response);
      },
      error:function(){
        $('#error').text("There was an error while processing your request.Please try again");
        $('#singlebtn').append(data);
      }
      
    });
    
  }else{
  /* code to do when locking */
  $('#switch_status').html('Switched off.');
  $.ajax({
    url:'https://api.thingspeak.com/update?api_key=DLQ0F7W5FGVO1I9Q&field8=0',
    type:'GET',
    data:{
      format:'text'
    },
    success:function(response){
      alert(response);
    },
    error:function(){
      $('#error').text("There was an error while processing your request.Please try again");
      $('#singlebtn').append(data);
    }
    
  });
  
}


/* reverse locking status */
$('#toggle_event_editing button').eq(0).toggleClass('locked_inactive locked_active btn-default btn-info');
$('#toggle_event_editing button').eq(1).toggleClass('unlocked_inactive unlocked_active btn-info btn-default');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "wrapper" align = "center">
  <div class="btn-group" id="toggle_event_editing">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info locked_active">OFF</button>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default unlocked_inactive">ON</button>
</div> 
<div class="alert alert-info" id="switch_status">Switched off.</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: thanks so much mate, i can now be able to see those request on my side on thingspeak. That button i want it be just one using bootstrap switch between on and off.

Comment: @user12443509 here is link of switch button that you can use for off and on w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_switch.asp , if answer is correct and work for you accept it to solved the topic